# Web server keeps redirecting to HTTP

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, ssl, cloudflare

I'm trying to use CloudFlare page rule to redirect to https but when I set it up it gives me the redirect loop and keeps changing back and fourth between http and https. I deleted my .htaccess file and deleted every redirect I had in the control panel. Still not working. Neither my webhost support or CloudFlare support can help. This is my page rule setup as CloudFlare support told me to set it:

URL pattern: http://*.kohlercoding.dk/*
setting: always use https

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out the problem is that I had my SSL setting on "Full" on CloudFlare. That means I have to have a verified certificate on my webhost which I didn't. That's why it didn't work. So changing it to "Flexible" fixed my problem. Or having a self-signed certificate on the webhost if they support it and, unlike UnoEuro, doesn't make you pay for HTTPS Protection.

Answer (score 0):

If you can edit the .htaccess file try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.website.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.website.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That didn't help. Removed the page rule and added "RewriteEngine on" at the top of the .htaccess file

Comment: Now, it just added www. to the url. That's really the only thing it did.